# How do I correctly format time in seconds using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do you change the format of an excel cell from "2m20s" to "140" (seconds)?

Also how do you change the format from "2:02" to "122" (seconds)?

Comment: I could give you an answer but please note that this is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems.

Comment: @Chris, Super User isn't a place for people to come and ask somebody to create an application for them.  However, this question is just about how to specify the format for a cell.  It isn't asking for a script or code.  Typical formatting also limits the number of seconds to values under a minute, so this isn't something obvious that would pop up in the first Google answer.  So this is a good question and it isn't at all out of scope.  And if you can provide a better answer than Werrf's, I encourage you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the cells currently contain a time value, or whether they contain text. If the value is literally "2m20s", then you're going to need a formula to convert that into a time format Excel can work with. You can check which you have by selecting the cell, opening the Format Cells dialogue, and looking at "General" format. If the preview on the right shows a number that looks completely unrelated to your time, likely something like 0.00162037, then what you have a time value, and you can get your result with just a format. If you see the same value in the preview space as you do in the cell, you're probably looking at a text string that will need additional processing.

For the exact format you entered here, "2m20s", and assuming that the time is in cell A1, we would use a formula like this: `=TIME(0,LEFT(A1,FIND("m",A1)-1),MID(A1,FIND("m",A1)+1,2))` This constructs a time value by finding the hour (0, in this case), then minute, then seconds. It identifies the minutes by starting from the first character and counting until it finds an "m" - this is the `LEFT(A1(FIND...` section. It then identifies by seconds by again finding the "m", then counting two space from there - this is the `MID(A1,FIND...` section.

This formula will likely give you a result like "12:02 AM". This is as expected.

Once you have the time converted to a useable format, you can open the Format Cells window (right-click on the cell and choose "Format Cells", or use Ctrl+1). On the left-hand side, select "Custom" as the category. On the right, you'll see a box labeled "Type". Delete what is currently in there and enter a new format: `[ss]`. The square brackets force the format to continue counting in second, rather than converting up to minutes or hours as the numbers increase. You should see the desired result.